# How can I make two labels inside two grids appear far left and far right?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML:

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="Red">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start">
        <Label Text="X" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
         <Label Text="Y" HorizontalOptions="End" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I wanted to see something like this with a red background from one side to another:

```
X                                                            Y
```

However what happens is this with a red background from one side to another:

```
X Y
```

Can someone give me advice on how I can achieve the effect I want and what might be going wrong? Note that the Label Text that's currently "Y" could actually be much longer and more than half of the width of the screen. Here I just used one character to simplify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your main `Grid` to `HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"` and your columns to take up the full width with `*`.

Now, you don't need the extra wrapping `Grid`s. You could use them, but it will complicate things. Then set the `Label`s to `HorizontalOptions="Start"` and `End` respectively.

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="Red" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="X" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="Y" HorizontalOptions="End" />
</Grid>
```

Resulting in:

[image: Result on iOS]

Comment: Hi Gerald,  This works but that means the ration of space allocated for the X and the Y will be 1:1 ?    in the app there is a lot more text and things on the 2nd column then it's a problem.  For example I tried this:  <Label Text="xhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh" HorizontalOptions="End" />  for the second column and the text is limited to just 50% of the width.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean